# How to create GeometryLineString with System.Spatial in c# 4.5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5, .net-4.5, spatial

I am trying to create & store line with Geometry data type in sql 2012, as I have never used this data type I was wondering how do I manipulate data in C#, then I found System.Spatial.

[MSDN Link Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.spatial%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

But I am not able to find any samples (there may be I am still searching), It would be great to know if anyone has knowledge on this topic or has any useful links to share with samples or demos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Spatial` is not compatible with Entity Framework. It was created to support spatial types on OData through WCF Data Services. More [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh525394%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Hence what you need to use is the `DbGeometry` class.

The problem is that you're using Entity Framework 5 and C# 4.0. You either need to use Entity Framework 6 or C# 4.5, as your current "mix" doesn't support spatial data.

Valid configurations:

- Entity Framework 5 with C# 4.5
- Entity Framework 6 with C# 4/4.5

Afterwards, you can create a line string like this:

```
var line = DbGeometry.FromText("LINESTRING (30 10, 10 30, 40 40)");
```

The text uses the [WKT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) notation.

Comment: Thanks, I am using DBGeometry class for now.